# Exclude products from a product category on a specific page in Entrada theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product, hook-woocommerce

I want to exclude all products/tours from the woocommerce category 'Excursions' (slug 'excursions-ru') on the 'Our tours' page (slug 'our-tours-ru'). Here is [this page](https://blackseatravel.ge/ru/our-tours-ru/)

I found [this solution here](https://gist.github.com/rynaldos/a9d357b1e3791afd9bea48833ff95994) So I use this code below, but it doesn't work for me.

Can't find where is my mistake.

```
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'get_subcategory_terms', 10, 3 );
function get_subcategory_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
    $new_terms = array();
    // if a product category and on the shop page
    // to hide from shop page, replace is_page('YOUR_PAGE_SLUG') with is_shop()
    if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && ! is_admin() && is_page('our-tours-ru') ) {
        foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
            if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, array( 'excursions-ru' ) ) ) {
                $new_terms[] = $term;
            }
        }
        $terms = $new_terms;
    }
    return $terms;
}
```

Comment: So difficult question?

Comment: Hi the function you are using is for other purpose, this function is to hide/remove categories from shop page not the products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Since none of the existing answers works for you and that you're using a child theme, I posted this answer which is specific to the [Entrada theme](https://themes.waituk.com/entrada-intro/) which you currently use on [your site](https://blackseatravel.ge/ru/our-tours-ru/).)*

The "Our Tours" page, as I could see it, is using the "*Listing Full Width (three column grid)*" template, which in the parent theme, it's located at `entrada/entrada_templates/listing-full-width-3column-grid.php`, and which uses this *template part*: `entrada/template-parts/grid-threecolumn.php`.

If you open it, you'd see this **custom query**:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'paged' => 1 
    );
$args = entrada_product_type_meta_query($args, 'tour' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

which is being used for the *primary* products section/grid on the "Our Tours" page.

So one easy way (and would likely work) for you to exclude the "Excursions" category from that query, or to exclude products from that category, is by copying `entrada/template-parts/grid-threecolumn.php` to the child theme folder (i.e. `entrada-child-picpic-v1_0/template-parts/grid-threecolumn.php`) and then customize the `$args` array anyway you like. And for your question, try adding this before/above the `$loop = new WP_Query( $args );`:

```
wp_reset_query(); // Just in case.
if ( is_page( 'our-tours-ru' ) ) {
    if ( ! isset( $args['tax_query'] ) ) {
        $args['tax_query'] = array();
    }

    // Excludes products from the "Excursions" category.
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array( 'excursions-ru' ),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    );
}
```

**Note:** That's the same [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) used in the other answers, except the one above is *specifically* for the `listing-full-width-3column-grid.php` template (or any other page templates using the `grid-threecolumn.php` *template part*).

Comment: It works! How is it possible to make it works for English version too? I mean, how to add the second/english page in `is_page( 'our-tours-ru' )` and the second category in `array( 'excursions-ru' )` ?!

Comment: Hi @Merkucio, thanks for accepting my answer. =) You can add another page like this: `is_page( array( 'out-tours-ru', 'slug', 'slug' ) )` where "slug" is the page slug, and likewise for the category: `array( 'excursions-ru`, 'slug', 'slug' )` where "slug" is the term/category slug.

Comment: I mean, thanks for the bounty award. And apologize for the code formatting - it should be `array( 'excursions-ru, 'slug', 'slug' )`. Let me know if you need further assistance. :)

Comment: Never mind :) So I add this pieces of code `if ( is_page( 'out-tours-ru', 'our-tours' ) ) {` and ` 'terms'    => array( 'excursions-ru', 'excursions' ),` but as you can see here https://blackseatravel.ge/en/our-tours/ it doesn't works. The first tour "Kakheti – the winemaking..." is in product category 'excursions' but it appears anyway.

Comment: Wow, it doesn't work even after I return your code(first version). Strange.

Comment: It should be `is_page( array( 'our-tours-ru', 'our-tours' ) )` and not `is_page( 'out-tours-ru', 'our-tours' )`. Try again? Make sure you use the `array()` and check the spelling.. like `our` and not `out`.. :)

Comment: For the category, `'terms' => array( 'excursions-ru', 'excursions' ),`. Sorry again about the typos, particularly the `'excursions-ru` (i.e. I forgot the closing `'`).

Comment: This is a screenshot of my file and your piece of code http://www.picz.ge/img/s1/1808/21/b/b5932d3bfc3e.jpg It worked perfectly, but stopped to work after I added the second page and category and doesn't work even if I will remove them. Right now it doesn't work on russian as well as on english version. I did nothing besides this changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178420/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-merkucio).

Answer (score 4):

**Update 1** *(see below)*

> The `get_terms` filter hook **is not made to filter products**, so not convenient in your case.

Woocommerce has 3 dedicated hooks to make customizations on the product query *(filter the products)*:

- `woocommerce_product_query` *(action hook)*
- `woocommerce_product_query_meta_query` *(filter hook)*
- **`woocommerce_product_query_tax_query`** *(filter hook)*

We will use the last one as it's the best one for your case.

Now to make this active only for a specific page, we will use WordPress [**`is_page()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) conditional tag:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'custom_exclude_products', 50, 2 );
function custom_exclude_products( $tax_query, $query ) {
    // Only on a specific page
    if( is_page('our-tours-ru') ){
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => array('excursions-ru'),
            'operator'  => 'NOT IN'
        );
    }
    return $tax_query;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**Update:**

As this is on a page, **you are certainly using a Woocommerce shortcodes** to display products on this particular page.

So in this case there is a dedicated hook for Woocommerce shortcodes:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'custom_shortcode_exclude_products', 50, 3 );
function custom_shortcode_exclude_products( $query_args, $atts, $loop_name ){
    if( is_page('our-tours-ru') ){
        $query_args['tax_query'] = array( array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'excursions-ru' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ) );
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works… It should also work for you.

> You need to be sure that this products are shown on a **Wordpress PAGE which slug is 'our-tours-ru'**, because if not no answer will work for you.

---

Last possibility that will work on mostly all cases, using `pre_get_posts` filter:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_query_exclude_products', 900, 1 );
function custom_query_exclude_products( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || is_search() ) return $query;

    if ( is_page('our-tours-ru') ){
        $query->set( 'tax_query', array( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'excursions ru' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ) ) );
    }

    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_query_exclude_products' );

    return $query;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Comment: Thanks you, but it doesn't work for me. Added in child's function.php. Tested few times.

Comment: @Merkucio I have added an update to my answer… Is really complicate to help you as we don't know if it's really on a page and we don't know how you are displaying the products on that page. I have tested my code creating a page which slug is `our-tours-ru`,  creating a product category which slug is `excursions-ru` and assigning that to some products that I wanted to exclude using my code… Then using the shortcode `[products]`, **it works and exclude products from `excursions-ru` product category**. Try to update your answer with more details, to get a working answer to your question.

Comment: I think it depends from Entrada theme. Too much customization are made in this theme, so regular hooks and methods doesn't work instead of other themes. But Sally CJ's method works. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't use Entrada theme. You didn't even mention it in your question…  I have added that on the title. My code works on mostly other themes.

Comment: Can this be adjusted to execute based ona div id intead of page name?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below for this

```
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

$tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

  $tax_query[] = array(
       'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
       'field' => 'slug',
       'terms' => array( 'excursions-ru' ),
       'operator' => 'NOT IN'
  );

  $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And where is the 'our-tours-ru' page here? I added your code in child theme's function.php. It doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the specific category from specific page, Please pass the page id in place of  YOUR_PAGE_ID , and put the below code in your current themes **functions.php** file.

```
 add_filter( 'get_terms', 'exclude_category_from_specific_page', 10, 3 );
    function exclude_category_from_specific_page( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
        $new_terms = array();
        // if a product category and on a page
        if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && ! is_admin() && is_page('YOUR_PAGE_ID')) {
            foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
                // Enter the name of the category you want to exclude 
                if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, array( 'excursions-ru' ) ) ) {
                    $new_terms[] = $term;
                }
            }
            $terms = $new_terms;
        }
        return $terms;
    }
```

**To remove product from specific category use below code**

/**
 * This code should be added to functions.php of your theme
 **/

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {
    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
    if ( ! is_page('YOUR_PAGE_ID') ) return;
    $q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'excursions-ru',
        'terms' => array( 'excursions ru' ),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    )));
    remove_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
}
```

I hope it will help you.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks you too, but it doesn't work for me as well as the LoicTheAztec's advice. Added in child's function.php. Tested few times.